# Composer rest server throwing error while performing transactions

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have my network up and running and the rest servers are running fine. But when it comes to performing a transaction, I am getting this error. How do you solve this? Has it anything to do with the number of peers I have defined or something to do with binding participants to identity. I am stuck.

```
{
  "error": {
    "statusCode": 500,
    "name": "Error",
    "message": "Error trying invoke business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.\nResponse from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: error executing chaincode: transaction returned with failure: [-5929085f]Calling chaincode Invoke() returned error response [ReferenceError: alert is not defined]. Sending ERROR message back to peer\n",
    "stack": "Error: Error trying invoke business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.\nResponse from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: error executing chaincode: transaction returned with failure: [-5929085f]Calling chaincode Invoke() returned error response [ReferenceError: alert is not defined]. Sending ERROR message back to peer\n\n    at _initializeChannel.then.then.then.then.catch (/Users/Admin/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-connector-hlfv1/lib/hlfconnection.js:912:34)\n    at <anonymous>"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message provides a clue as to the problem. On invoking chaincode your TP fails with the following error

`ReferenceError: alert is not defined`

Looks like you have tried to use a function called alert. This doesn't exist. If you used it in playground with the Web Browser connector then it works only because all the code executes in the browser and a browser defines the alert global function.